# Android Studio 3.1.4: java.time.LocalDate" is not supported

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.1.4, Java 8, Gradle 4.4.

in my build.gradle:

```
        compileSdkVersion 26
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26

      compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

In my POJO

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
public class Product {
    private Date redeemed_date;
    private LocalDate myLocalDate;
}
```

I must use `minSdkVersion 18` because it's client requirement.

But when build I get error:

```
error: Field "myLocalDate" of type "java.time.LocalDate" is not supported.
```

Comment: Java 8 Date API is not supported by Android. You can use e.g. this library as substitute: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: What is you compileSdkVersion ?

Comment: @AnisuzzamanBabla  compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: @Christopher Since Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0, you can use a subset of java.time (see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The JavaDocs for `LocalDate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate) show that it was added in API Level 26. Your `minSdkVersion` is below that, and so `LocalDate` will not be supported on all the devices that you wish to run on.

Your choices are:

1. Raise your `minSdkVersion` to 26, or
2. Use something else, such as [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), that [Christopher recommended in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808903/android-studio-3-1-4-java-time-localdate-is-not-supported#comment90572947_51808903)

Answer (score 3):

Since april 2020 with **Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0**, you can enable support for using a number of Java 8 language APIs (see all supported APIs: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)

> To enable support for these language APIs on any version of the
> Android platform, update the Android plugin to 4.0.0 (or higher) and
> include the following in your module’s build.gradle file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support